# Question for CSS specialists, css input:checked and embeded svg as href

Tags: html, css, svg, href

I have a very annoying problem. Maybe someone knows a solution. I want to access a linked SVG via css input:checked. But I can't get this to work.

**html:**
`<label class="label"><input class="input" id="blabla" type="checkbox" /><svg class="grfx"><use xlink:href="#checkbox" /></svg>...`

and at the bottom:
`<svg> .... <symbol> id="checkbox" ...`

**css:**
`input:checked ~ svg #checkbox {....}` **(does not work)**

Any ideas?

Kind regards
Gabriel

Comment: the contents of <use> are in the shadow DOM and a CSS selector cannot cross the shadow DOM boundary. See https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#UseStyleInheritance

Comment: Thanks but - NO. Does not work. The variable itself works. But if you change it in `input:checked` as mentioned in the othter post, nothing happens. So unfortunately there is only the javascript solution I wanted to avoid.

Comment: I know now why it doesn't work with the variables. In this example he accessed style of the SVG. But you don't have to do that via variables.

Because everything that is set within the SVG via styling can also be done via the styling of the HTML page. He would not have needed the variables in this example. He would have had to assign an id to the circle and then style this id.

in the .css file
#circleid {
fill: red;
}

in SVG
...<circle id="circleid" ...

But you can't access parameters that are not in the styling. So you can't move the circle, for example.